Composite API is not working with Master detail relationship
I have two custom Objects:

CustomA
CustomB

CustomA has master-detail relationship with CustomB object. I would like to create record of both the objects in a single API call using composite API as defined here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm but it's not working.
I am calling API services/data/v60.0/composite/tree/CustomA with the below payload
{
"records" :[{
    "attributes" : {"type" : "CustomA__c", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
    "Name" : "Testing",
    "CustomB__c" : {
      "records" : [{
         "attributes" : {"type" : "CustomB__c", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
         "name" : "Testing"
         }]
      }
  }]
}


and I am getting below error
[
    {
        "message": "Cannot deserialize instance of reference from START_OBJECT value { or request may be missing a required field at [line:4, column:20]",
        "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
    }
]


I have validated the payload JSON and that's correct so it shouldn't be JSON_PARSER_ERROR.
It works if I remove the master-detail relationship so there is something wrong with defining the record of the CustomB object. I have also checked object permissions and that looks fine.
Can someone point out what's going wrong here?

Refer to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_record_manipulation.htm#topic-title
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_subrequest_result.htm

Nested Record: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm

In the JSON, You need to pass the relationship name instead of the object API name of the CustomB object.

Thanks for the comments @TusharJadav. I have checked those links and one is already mentioned in the question.
The relationship name is the same as the API name of the CustomB object in the CustomA object and that's the reason it looks confusing. I have also tried with CustomB__r but I get different error with that Cannot deserialize instance of <unknown> from START_ARRAY value [ or request may be missing a required field"

Is there any required field in CustomB other then the Name?

No, that's the only field

Check this may help you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118454/writing-nested-custom-object-records
